# Upgraded R to 3.2.4 and I want Revolution R enterprise's functions back

Tags: r, r-package, revolution-r

I installed the latest version of R 3.2.4 and I used to run the RRE version of R (based on R 3.2.1). I want to ask if there is anything I can do to make the RRE functions run on a R 3.2.4 ?

Comment: Downgrade your R version back to 3.2.1(3*) until they RRE is updated and continue using R as usual. Is there a reason why you need to use 3.2.4 now?

Comment: wait till they update to 3.2.4; until then you can use [MRO 3.2.3](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/download/)

Comment: To close voters: this question has nothing to do with "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Comment: @TJGorrie thanks, well some packages does  not support that R build anymore like Caret (when i install an old version of it the compilation fails during install)

Comment: What do you mean? The [CRAN version of caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) only requires R > 2.1.

Comment: after loading the caret package i can't use the downsample() function under that package... am i doing it right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RRE installs are based off a specific version of the underlying R runtime. You'll have to use the version of R that was originally installed until a new release of Microsoft R Server (the rebranded Revolution R Enterprise) comes out, unfortunately.